# Downloading a File from box.com

Tags: file, download, box

I'm trying to automate  downloading a set of csv files from a box.com folder that has been shared with me because data gets added to the files and I want a python script to take that data every week and import it into my formatted MySQL database. Unfortunately, I've never used box before and when trying to look up ways to do this, my brain gets fried by all the technical pieces that I can't understand involving box developer and creating apps. Can someone explain the basic process of how I would go about accessing and downloading these files with python? I don't necessarily need help with the coding as long as I understand the process of what to access.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to go about this.

1.: Using headless chrome simulating you interacting with the website, eg. Emulating the user input for downloading the files. (Kind of hacky and could break really soon)

2.: Reverse-Engineering the sign-in and api to list and download files. This would be the optimal solution, as it is way more efficient, but requires more effort. You can go about this by opening chromes devtools and looking at the request the site makes. For starters, you could sign in by hand and “steal” your own auth token, so your script won’t need the authentication functionality.

Note: this are just some pointers, as I havent specifically looked at the website.